# Call method in another class by Casting?

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting

Ok so lets say I have Class A and Class B. In Class A lets say I implemented a method called saveImage and implemented the method in the .m.

Is it simple enough to say that if I do [(ClassA*)self saveImage]; That method in Class A will get called?

What is the logic behind this and can anyone explain it so I can understand a bit better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting is mostly just for compile-time type checking (note that for safety, it's always wise to cast when you send a message to an object of type `id`. See [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/big-weakness-of-objective-c-weak-typing.html). It's ignored by the compiler (and therefore the runtime). Casting is just a promise to the compiler that yes, that object is really is really Class A, not Class B. So if you tried to compile that, unless `self` is actually an instance of `Class A` or a subclass (as you promised), you're going to raise an exception. AKA the runtime will get mad if you break your promises :)